# How to fix this exception 'Tesseract engine has not been initialized'

Tags: c#, pdf, tesseract

```
 OCRProcessor processor = new OCRProcessor(@"\App_Data\Tesseract binaries\");
 PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument("fed excel.pdf");
 processor.Settings.Language = "eng";
 processor.PerformOCR(loadedDocument, @"\App_Data\Tessdata\");
 loadedDocument.Save("Sample.pdf");
 loadedDocument.Close(true);
```

I m getting System.exeception

> 'Tesseract engine has not been initialized

...while loading Tessdata.

Comment: "while loading Tessdata" does not clealry point to a specific line.

Comment: This can be helpful - https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/128497/quottesseract-engine-has-not-been-initializedquot

Comment: https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-1